# Using CSS for layout, clearing float for stating on next line ?? Need to create a layout of 2 cols and 5 rows

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have created a layout using DIVs rather than tables. It seems to be working... I had to clear:none after each div consisting of column and content.

But i end up with an extra line under each 2 columns before the other 2 columns start. I will outlay my code below, what am i doing wrong?.. What i want to do is create a table like layout but using divs consisting of 5 rows and each row have 2 columns.

```
 <div id="column1" style="float:left;width:200px;">1st Title</div>
 <div id="container1" style="float:left;"> <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div id="column2" style="float:left;width:200px;">2nd Title</div>
 <div id="container2" style="float:left;"> <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS class that would make the problem all go away.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yay clearfix. I still think this shouldn't be necessary though (although I use it a lot) :) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can get the same effect by adding `clear: left` to your `column` `div`s and `clear: right` to your `container` `div`s.

Edit: In fact, I would expect that the `clear:left` in the `column`s would be enough, but if that was true, making table-like layouts using floats would be easy, and it never is.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use *display* attribute rather than *float*, e.g. (you'll need to group your divs within divs with class "row"):

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
}

#column1, #container1, #column2, #container2 {
    display: table-cell;
}
```